# Как найти номер и количество слайдов в карусели owl carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть карусель [Owl Carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) в которой хочу получать номер текущего слайда и количество всех слайдов (вместо 1 и N) - как это можно сделать?

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  items: 1,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  afterAction: afterAction
});

function afterAction() {
  updateResult(".currentItem", this.owl.currentItem);
}
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 10rem;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
</div>
<p>№1 из N</p>
```

Обращаю внимание на тот момент, что слайдов может быть разное количество (не ориентируемся на подсчет слайдов в `html`) и карусель зациклена в бесконечность, т.е. количество слайдов в исходном коде и `html` не совпадают (там есть клонированные слайды)
[Рабочий фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/152/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  items: 1,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  onInitialized: function(e) {
    $('.counter').text('1 из ' + this.items().length)
    console.log();
  }
});
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  $('.counter').text(++e.page.index + ' из ' + e.item.count)
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 10rem;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
</div>
<p class='counter'>№1 из N</p>
```

Comment: да, спасибо! но осталось чуть-чуть докрутить, т.к. при переходе от последнего слайда к первому показывает 8, а потом сразу 2,3 и т.д.

Comment: Так там -1 специально стоит

Comment: и тем не менее попробуйте после 7 слайда переключиться на 1 - показывает 8 из 7, а не 1

Comment: не знаю с чем может быть связано, ни разу не получилось такой ситуации

Comment: @ sivik_xes т.е. вот такого у вас нет?http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1604/1e/acc6bf82cb81.png

Comment: нету, можно отделить математическую операцию от конкатенации  (e.item.index - 1) - возьмите в скобки

Comment: нее, это ничего не дает.. будем еще думать.. - вы через хром смотрите?

Comment: Именно так, через Chrome на OSX

Comment: хочется отметить решение как правильное, но загадка с номером слайда все покоя не дает..

Comment: т.е. вы уверены, что у вас по ссылке http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/154/ в консоли не такая последовательность выводится, как здесь? http://s018.radikal.ru/i504/1604/b7/86f9b7dcfce7.png потому что я у кого ни спрошу - у всех как у меня точно также

Comment: у меня в консоли числа от 2 до 8

Comment: у меня вот так работает http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/155/ а у вас? только это в случае статического варианта

Comment: Так у меня тоже работает, но вы же не будете раздувать массив каждый раз когда у вас меняется количество слайдов

Comment: да, не буду, но этот вариант по крайней мере и вас, и у сеня работает - осталось найти универсальный вариант, т.е. впереди должны стоять (e.item.count-1),e.item.count,`последовательность от 1 до последнего слайда`,1,2. теперь остался вопрос как разместить здесь такую последовательность..

Comment: вот так - http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/156/ Единственное, что во всплывающем окне или фрейме не работает..

Comment: nice - но все же рекомендовал бы вам перейти на другой слайдер, этот с его багами как-то не очень

Comment: у этой карусели есть ряд несомненных преимуществ, которых у других нет. к тому же в тему встроен. добавьте исправленный вариант в ваш ответ и я помечу его как правильный

Comment: не я на самом деле доделывал решение, если вы конечно так хотите, то хорошо. спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно выводит номер текущего слайда и количество общих слайдов при зацикленной карусели `loop: true`. Протестировано в версии Owl Carousel 2.3.4.

```
$carousel.on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {

  var $menuCounterThis = $('.counter__this'), // Контейнер вывода текущего слайда
      $menuCounterTotal = $('.counter__total'), // Контейнер вывода общего количества слайдов
      menuCloned = $( this ).find( '.cloned' ).length, // Количество клонированных элементов
      menuIndex = event.item.index, // Номер текущего слайда
      menuCount = event.item.count; // Общее количество слайдов (без клонированных)

  if ( menuIndex > menuCount ) {
      $menuCounterThis.text( menuIndex - menuCloned + ( menuCloned - menuCount )   );
  } else {
      $menuCounterThis.text( menuIndex );
  }

  $menuCounterTotal.text( menuCount );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Неправильные значения текущего слайда могут быть из-за нескольких причин:
1. Бесконечный слайдер дает дополнительные слайды с классом .cloned
2. Некоторые параметры выдают номер текущего слайда до переключения

У меня работает следующий код:

```
owlSlider.owlCarousel({
    onInitialized: slideInit
})

function slideInit(e){
    // определяем количество клонировнных слайдов при инициализации
    owlSlider.prevCloned = e.item.index;
}

owlSlider.on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    var curPos = e.property.value - owlSlider.prevCloned + 1;
        curPos = curPos > 0 ? curPos : e.page.count;
    $('.slideCounter').html(curPos + ' / ' + e.page.count);
}
```